# Google reCaptcha implementation; response is always NULL

Tags: php, recaptcha, captcha

I have the following code for recaptcha veryfication.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$postfields = array(
  'secret' => '------Private Key------',
  'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
);

var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

$options = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);


$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
```

The problem is that the response I get is always NULL, no matter what. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks

Comment: According with the Google Developer documentation (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php), this can be done with a library provides for them, are you using it?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is at the end of the head tag

Comment: In that case, you don't have to do any curl instead do it through of library methods.

Comment: Do you still have the issue?